# arraylist java pet name and chip number

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create a class to store a list of dog details objects.
I have the class DogDetails and then another called Vetrinary where I want to create an ArrayList to store the dog details. This is how far I've got:

CLASS TO STORE THE DOG'S DETAILS

```
/**
 * represents the details of a dog's identity
 * pin for a vetrinary.
 */
public class DogDetails
{
    // the dog name
    private String name;
    // the dogs pin
    private int pin;

    /**
     * Create a new pet with a given name and chip pin.
     */
    public DogDetails(String name, int pin)
    {   
            this.name = name;
            this.pin = pin;


    }

    /**
     * Return the name of this dog.
     */
    public String getDogName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Return the chip of the dog.
     */
    public int getPin()
    {
        return pin;
    }
}
```

CLASS TO CREATE ARRAY LIST OF DOG'S DETAILS

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A class to store a list of DogDetails objects
 */
public class Vetrinary
{
    //An ArrayList for storing student loans.
    private ArrayList<DogDetails> dogDetails;
    int id;
    String amount;

   /**
    * Add method taking the dog's name and pin 
    */
   public void addDog(String name, int pin)
   {

    }
}
```

I am a bit unsure what to do to, should I be able to add the dogs details into both the veterinary class or should it all be going through the DogDetails class to go there.

Comment: *"I am a bit unsure what to do.."*  Start with 'ask a question'.

Comment: Please ask a clear question. Otherwise there is no way for us to help you.

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: I am having trouble trying to understand what the question's asking of me when it says:

add a method taking two parameters: the name of a dod and it's pin The method should create a DogDetails object using those two parameters and store the DogDetails in the collection.

Comment: So, in the addDog method you created, construct a new DogDetails object using the parameters passed in. Then add that DogDetails object to the arraylist. The answer below, by Gangaraju, shows how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want to construct the dog in your veterinary class: you should give him a `Dog` object instead.

Outside of both these classes (for example in your `main` method) construct a dog. Then add him to the list in your veterinary object.

```
Veterinary vet = new Veterinary();
Dog someDog = new Dog("Doggie", 2);
```

Then add it to your veterinary:

```
vet.addDog(someDog);
```

You veterinary class looks like this:

```
public class Veterinary {
   private List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();

   public void addDog(Dog dog) {
       dogs.add(dog);
   } 
}
```

The reason you create the `Dog` outside of `Veterinary` is because of extensibility. Should you decide tomorrow that you also want a `Date` in your dog's constructor to mark its date of birth, then you would have to change all your methods. This is not the case if you just pass a `Dog` around, you'd just have to change the initialization.

If you are forced to go that way though:

```
public class Veterinary {
   private List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();

   public void addDog(String name, int pin) {
       Dog dog = new Dog(name, pin);
       dogs.add(dog);
   } 
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. There is just a small typo in the constructor arguments when you are creating new Dog(String,int).

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. +1  ;)